# Action or Interface to populate class data from a collection

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, delegates, action

I have a vertex class which contains x,y,z coordinates. This class has multiple instances which are contained in the following dictionary:

```
// Vertex Collection
var Vertexs = new Dictionary<int, Vertex>();

public class Vertex
{
    public double x, y, z;
}
```

I have three more classes as follows:

```
public abstract class Element
{ }

public class TRI : Element
{
    public int vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
    public double v1x, v1y, v1z;
    // and so on for vertex 2 & 3
}

public class QUAD : Element
{
    public int vertex1, vertex2, vertex3, vertex4;
    public double v1x, v1y, v1z;
    // and so on for vertex 2, 3 & 4
}
```

there are multiple instances of both TRI and QUAD classes. These are contained in a dictionary as follows:

```
// Element Collection
var Elements = new Dictionary<int, Element>();
```

The Elements Key (int value) will coincide with the TRI/QUAD fields named `vertex1` and so on. I don't know the coordinates of the vertices upon instantiation of the Element-type classes. So after the dictionary is created, I need to loop through and pull the vertex data from the Vertex dictionary and use it to fill in the blanks.

```
foreach (var Elm in Elements)
{
    // this is where I need help.
}
```

The QUAD elements need to pull four vertices from the Vertexs dictionary and the TRI elements need to pull three. So my TRI function should look something like this.

```
public void fetch_vertex_coords(Vertex vertex1, Vertex vertex3, Vertex vertex3)
{
    v1x = vertex1.x; v1y = vertex1.y; v1z = vertex1.z;
    v2x = vertex2.x; v2y = vertex2.y; v2z = vertex2.z;
    v3x = vertex3.x; v3y = vertex3.y; v3z = vertex3.z;
}
```

The problem is that the QUAD needs to call a void function as well, but it will have 4 inputs instead of three.

I have very little experience with interfaces and all delegate types (only simple book examples which aren't helping me) so I don't really know how to proceed. I need a function "fetch_vertex_coords" that will take 3 arguments and one that will take 4 and I don't know if an interface or action (delegate) should be used here.

Am I making this hard on myself for using the "Elements" dictionary value as Element? FYI my abstract class "Element" literally is blank because I don't know if I should populate it with fields since the derived classes already have fields. Any comment on this would be appreciated as well.

There is always the fallback of creating more dictionaries; one for TRI and one for QUAD and then combining them later after I filled in the vertex data using simple methods. But I have gotten this far and I would like to learn something practical about interfaces and/or delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want TRI and QUAD to inherit Element? As you said, Element is empty, which means TRI and QUAD don't have any common interface. How are you going to use that dictionary if you manage to populate it with TRIs and QUADs? Take one item, cast it one or the other and have "if" statements everywhere? You should think about how they are going to be used. That will help you extract the interface if there is any. Otherwise, I don't see any point why you should try to force two types to inherit one base type. You might just use two dictionaries `Dictionary<int, TRI> and Dictionary<int, QUAD>`.

Comment: The program will display graphics. Later on in my gameLoop I will have draw functions that draw the TRI and QUAD elements. I wanted to keep this as compact as possible so... TRI and QUAD inherit from Element so that I could lump them into a single dictionary. This way I only have one dictionary to loop thru while updating the environment. You mentioned that I would have to cast each item one way or another... I thought that either an interface or action could determine which method to use (3 vertx or 4 or more). I want to abstain from multiple Dict at the moment because I actually have > 10.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you think about how TRI and QUAD are they same, they both store "lists" of Vertices, except TRI has three while QUAD has four.  Instead of having two classes with different numbers of discrete variables v1, v2, v3, why not just have a single concrete Element class which contains an array of Vertex objects?  That might allow you to write code which processes the vertices more easily.  You don't have to worry about whether you have a TRI or a QUAD and call different methods, you just have to look at the length of the array and loop that many times.

Comment: That is an interesting solution, however, my derived classes have many methods specific to that shape so a single group would create problems while fixing others. Perhaps I need to pass the entire Elements dictionary to the method then loop through the vertex fields. I could put them in a list like you mentioned. Can I pass an entire Dictionary to a method, is that possible/practical?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can pass a dictionary to a method.  It is an object just like any other.

Comment: Does passing the entire dictionary come with any performance penalty? I think the answer is no because it is passed by reference, but I just wanted an objective opinion on it.

Comment: No, there is no performance penalty.  You are correct that it is passed by reference.